Hose interface between two standards for power washing
It's bad enough that every tool (lawn mower, drill, leaf blower, etc...) uses its own Lithium-ion batteries, but now I'm finding that this interfacing problem also exists between two hose standards.
(Aside and, admittedly, a rant: how did the world reach the AA and C batteries standard a century ago? Where politicians more diligent in enforcing a standard? Were those standard batteries adopted voluntarily?)
Back on topic, my power washer (PowerPlay Spyder) has the following wand connection.

But that company does not produce an undercarriage sprayer. One of the ones available is from the greenish-yellow brand (Ryobi). It looks like this.

How can I interface this wand to that undercarriage washer? Does either/both of these look like standard connections? One solution is to simply buy a new powerwasher with its own undercarriage washer, but this incompatibility means wasting a ton of storage space (and burning money to duplicate functions).
Edit (following DanV's answer)
One attachment does indeed seem like it would solve the problem on the power washer end.

But whether the two parts would be compatible just because they look similar remains doubtful.

There are no standards for tools as you have found out.
Your power washer is a light duty tool intended for "around the house" use.
An undercarriage sprayer is not within the realm of intended uses for that product.
You could purchase a gas powered pressure washer with more available tool options. However, the attachment can still be an issue as the male/ female fittings for quick connect, (see the attached pic) have variations and are not all compatibles with each other. They can be purchased in male/female sets and threaded on to compatible hoses.

Perhaps you can disconnect the main discharge hose and replace it with a Hose set so you can get the compatible fitting for the tools you need. This will give you the most options without buying another washer.

The salesperson at the nearest big-box store generously offered that they will take the undercarriage washer back if I went ahead with my initial thought of checking whether I'd get enough outflow by hooking it simply to a garden hose — and found that it's unsatisfactory. Attempting to modify the connection is a whole different game though. If you're reading this and can comment one way or the other (because you have this tool), please do.

The issue is NOT the tool the issue is the type of fitting (See red arrow in the pic on my post)  This fitting is replaceable.  It is most likely 1/4NPT.  Getting that connected to the male/female fittings on the wand of your washer and have it usable, is about impossible. This is why I suggested a new hose set for your PW. You may be able to change the hose and that will give you a number of tool options.

Yes, I understood what you meant. I couldn't tell whether you're also asserting it is removable. Now I see that you do. In other words, I can add my own fitting to the undercarriage washer. Now I "just" need to find out whether I can do the same to my power washer.

Providing a pic of both ends of the discharge hose would help us understand what you are working with there.

I thought I did provide pictures of both ends. Could you clarify what you mean?

You posted a pic of the WAND, not a HOSE.

I think you need this: Quick-Connect Pressure Washer Spray Wand from a nationwide discount tool chain.

This is a good lead. I edited the question with the picture of one such promising product. Search ongoing...
